# Use of cross validation for Polynomial Regression

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I've two text files which contains my data.
One text file on X axis another text file on Y axis
Then using scatter function from python I did the data visualization
After that, I used polyfit function from python to get the curve which will fit my data
In that polyfit function we need to write degree of the polynomial we want eg. 2 or 3
Now let's consider I got 4 such a equations of degrees 2,3,4,5 respectively.
Now here comes my problem.
Among all those equations I got, how can I select the best equation which fits my data. I want to use cross validation here. Any high level library function can be use. My language is Python.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want this:

[K-fold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html#sklearn.cross_validation.KFold)

If you want say MSE of each check out section 3.1.1 here:

[cross validated metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#computing-cross-validated-metrics)

Answer (score 1):

If instead of Numpy's polyfit function, you use one of [Scikit's generalized linear models with polynomial features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html), you can then apply  [GridSearch with Cross Validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV) and pass in degrees as a parameter. It will find the best model based on the input features (i.e. 2,3,4,5).